# How can I recognizing the reduced features after applying PCA?

Tags: pca, multivariate-analysis, feature-selection, dimensionality-reduction, feature-engineering

I am working on the "global index of economic freedom" data which has 26 exploratory variables. I am trying to reduce the features using PCA and I am able to recognize that the first 5 PCs show maximum variance. I want to further apply a multiple linear regression algorithm but I cannot really recognize the features that have the maximum variance from the PCs. How can I recognize the original features with the maximum variance in python?

Comment: Could you please be more specific in your question? When using PCA, it is usually the case that the components will not align with the initial vectors. I guess that you'd like to "recognise" the initial variables from your PCA. But there is nothing more to it than the decomposition, the mathematical representation as a mixture of the original vectors. And what has a programming language to do with the statistics?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. That does answer my question, i reckon its better to you Principal component regression instead. The programming language matters because in R the representation is much bettrt and it is possible to recognize the variables whereas for python it is not.